# Как вызвать конвейерную функцию с результатом другой функции как аргумент? PLS-00306: неверное количество или типы аргументов

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как вызвать конвейерную функцию с результатом другой конвейерной функции в качестве аргумента?

Есть такие пользовательские типы данных:

```
create or replace TYPE RESULTING_RECORD_RT force as object (
    MEASURE VARCHAR2(1024), VALUE NUMBER)
/
create or replace TYPE RESULTING_COLS_RT IS TABLE OF RESULTING_RECORD_RT
/
```

И пакет с двумя конвейерными функциями:

```
create or replace package pipe_pkg as
    function pipe_func_emp return RESULTING_COLS_RT PIPELINED;
    function pipe_func_emp2 (input_Set IN resulting_cols_rt) return RESULTING_COLS_RT PIPELINED;
end;
/
create or replace package body pipe_pkg as
    function pipe_func_emp return RESULTING_COLS_RT PIPELINED is
        test_tbl resulting_cols_rt:= resulting_cols_rt();
    begin
        test_tbl(1):=resulting_record_rt('A',1);
        test_tbl.extend;
        test_tbl(2):=resulting_record_rt('B',2);
        PIPE ROW(test_tbl(1));
        PIPE ROW(test_tbl(2));
        return;
    end;
    function pipe_func_emp2(input_Set IN resulting_cols_rt) return RESULTING_COLS_RT PIPELINED is
        v_tmp VARCHAR2(10240);
        l_res SYS_REFCURSOR;
        recs resulting_record_rt;
    begin
        open l_res for select * from table(input_Set);
        loop
            fetch l_res into recs;
            PIPE ROW(recs);
            exit when l_res%notfound;
        end loop;
        close l_res;
        return;
    end;
end;
/
```

Когда пытаюсь вызвать одну функцию с другой функцией в качестве аргумента, то получаю ошибку:

```
select * 
from TABLE (pipe_pkg.pipe_func_emp2 (
                CURSOR (select * from TABLE (pipe_pkg.pipe_func_emp()))))
```

> ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PIPE_FUNC_EMP2'

Что делаю не так?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Pipelining Between PL/SQL Table Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67383002) от участника [@brungel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15831450/brungel)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67383002

Answer (score 3):

Функция `pipe_func_emp2` ожидает `RESULTING_COLS_RT` в качестве аргумента, но выражение `CURSOR` создаст `REF CURSOR`. Это разные типы данных.

Попробуйте простой [воспроизводимый пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1af6e3d5134f9a6c373ab5887cc8833):

```
create or replace type somerow  as object (id int, val varchar2 (8))
/
create or replace type sometab is table of somerow
/
create or replace package pack as
    function func1 return sometab pipelined;
    function func2 (cur sys_refcursor) return sometab pipelined;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    function func1 return sometab pipelined is
        tab sometab := sometab (somerow (1,'AAA'), somerow (2,'BBB'));
    begin
        for i in 1..tab.count loop 
            pipe row (tab(i)); 
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
    function func2 (cur sys_refcursor) return sometab pipelined is
        sr somerow;
    begin
        loop
            fetch cur into sr;
            exit when cur%notfound;
            pipe row (sr);
        end loop;
        close cur;
        return;
    end;
end;
/
```

Запрос и его результат:

```
select * 
from table (pack.func2 (
    cursor (select value (p) from table (pack.func1()) p)))
/

        ID VAL     
---------- --------
         1 AAA     
         2 BBB
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389699) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>